# Forem Gem on Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Kindly, would anyone tell me how to use [Forem](https://github.com/radar/forem) gem on Rails 3.0? By the way am using Rails 3.0.10. Forem documentation states that it works with rails >=3.1. Is there any way to have it work properly with 3.0 ?

Comment: Mohamed, could you be more specific ? Using a gem with Rails 3 consists in adding it to your project Gemfile. The Forem README explains how to use the generator to install required components once your Gem is available. Do you have any particular problem to solve ?

Comment: Yes, in the README file of the gem, they say that it's for Rails 3.1 and 3.2. When I tried to install it on Rails 3.0.10 it gives me an error in installation. Do you want me post the error?

Comment: I would advice you to edit your question and make clear the problem you are trying to solve (i.e. "Forem documentation states that it works with rails >=3.1. Is there any way to have it work properly with 3.0 ?"). Stackoverflow users are really good at finding useful answers, but you'll have to ask the good question :). By the way, any clue (error codes, process you followed and steps achieved, code & configuration) on your particular issue will help Rails developers make useful comments and suggestions, even if they don't know Forem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, could you raise the question? it's -1 =)

Comment: Is it a brand new application or are you trying to add Forem to an existing one ? If so, is it big ?

Comment: Any error code would also be helpful.

Comment: An existing one... The only obvious solution (for me) till now is to upgrade to Rails 3.1 ... But I don't want to do that.

Comment: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    forem (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 3.1) ruby

    rails (3.0.10)

Comment: Upgrading frequently is a good habit. Rails is evolving really really fast. The more you wait, the more it will be painful. Anyhow, you could try to fork the code on GitHub and reference your fork in your project Gemfile, modify the gemspec to downgrade the dependency to Rails, then move the content of `app/assets` to your app `public` directory. I'm not sure it will work but could be a good start.

Comment: The error message states that your app depends on 3.0.10, but the gem on ~>3.1 which leads to a conflict Bundler cannot resolve. See my previous comment.